# Backbone events selector - like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

With a plain jQuery selector for an event I might do this:

```
var ele = $('ul.list li');
$('a',ele).on('click',function(){});
```

Which targets all links under `ele` in the DOM (I think!).

With backbone, my current events function in a view looks like:

```
events: function(){
    var e = {};
    e['click a'] = 'someFunction';
    return e;
}
```

How do I do the same using backbone, that is, target all links under `ele`..?

Specifically the element I want to target is the `el` from the same view, which is created (not referenced) using `tagName: 'li'`.

**UPDATE:**

So I guess what I'm really asking is:

Using Backbone views, how do I attach events *only* to DOM elements that are children of the view's DOM element..?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, that's already the case, the events in a Backbone view are scoped to the view el.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  // stuff

  events: {
    "click .icon":          "open",
    "click .button.edit":   "openEditDialog",
    "click .button.delete": "destroy"
  },

  // more stuff

});
```

Events defined in the `MyView` events object will only apply to DOM elements inside of the defined `el`.

Take a look at: http://backbonejs.org/#View-el for more info on `el` (and `$el`)